# How to include a page in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to convert my HTML website into react , I've created header, footer and home page. Now I want to navigate to inner page on click of image on home page.
I used router and switch too but unable to call that page.
I am getting an error 'Listing' is not defined (page name is Listing)

I am adding the code too

```
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import Listing from './Listing'
```

The above I added on top of my home page

```
<Link to='/app/listing'>
    <a href="palm-valley.html" class="property-slider-img bg-xs" style={{backgroundImage: "url(" + "images/header/palm-valley-header.jpg" + ")",}}>
    </a>
</Link>
```

This is how I added link

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/listing"><Listing/></Route>
</Switch>
```

And this is how I used switch

Comment: React native or react dom?

Comment: @mousetail React dom

Comment: Then don't tag native

Comment: @mousetail okay

Comment: Given the code you've provided, it's unclear what the problem is. Please create an online sandbox (for example via https://codesandbox.io) to demonstrate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing **Listing** as **Inner**, so you need to use `<Inner />`.

Comment: Cannot find file: 'Listing.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: './src/components/listing.js'.   I got this error after changing the Inner as Listing

Answer (score 0):

Change your import to

```
import Listing from './Listing'
```

Also **to** does not match any **path**, so change

```
<Link to='/listing'> ... <Link>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did the same on link an error is coming "Cannot find file: 'Listing.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: './src/components/listing.js'." and the file is there I double checked

Comment: @AnkitDutt where your route file exist, is it in src ? seems like you are are not giving a correct path

Comment: @AnkitDutt ./Listing means your route file and your listing component are in the same directory...Kindly correct your path, it may supposed to be ./components/listing

Comment: Its in the components only.. but my home file is also in components

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to but a `<a></a>` in your `<Link></Link>` you can add a className on the `<Link></Link>` if you want but it's not important

I saw that you have import Router but make sur that you use it like that:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route/>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Then you shouldn't use the `<Route/>` like that, here an exemple:

```
<Route
  exact
  key='/path'
  path='/path'
  render={(routeProps) => (<ComponentToRender/>)}
/>
```

And if they say that 'Listing' is not defined this is because you have not import it

Comment: How to import listing as it is already there in the components as listing.js

Comment: import Component from './path/component.js' check if you are exporting your component as ```export default Component```. If you are just exporting it like ```export Component``` you have to import it with the exact same name.